# running a class in junit for two time in a sequence

Tags: eclipse, maven, automation, junit5, test-suite

As part of my project, I have two classes one for uninstall and the other for install. for creating the test suit I have to run first uninstall then install and again uninstall.

I am using this for my suit, but it is considering it only once i.e it is running uninstall first then install. second time uninstall class is not running

```
@SelectClasses( {TestUnistallServer.class, TestInstallServer.class,TestUnistallServer.class})
@IncludeTags("UpgradecustomInstall")
public class InstallServer  {

}
```

`@RepeatedTest(5)` annotation will not solve this problem as it does not help in the sequential running of the class

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean by `install` and `uninstall`.. Apart from that you know that things like `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` existing? Furthermore Can you explain why you need to  have a suite?

Comment: Install and uninstall are the classes. yes, I am aware of those tags.
when we do a testing we need to run the suit which covers all the test cases

Comment: First the suite is something I don't understand exactly what the purpose of this is... second can you elaborate more in detail when/before/after you need to execute the class/methods? Maybe an extension might be the right way but currently I don't know what you are trying to achieve...